# UICollectionView - Please help- getting a "type NSException" error when running

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview

I'm totally new to Xcode. This is my first attempt at UICollectionView. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the error I am getting.

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

here is my code.

```
PatternViewCell.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PatternViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property ( nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet UIImageView *patternImageView;
@property ( nonatomic, weak)IBOutlet UILabel *patternLabel;
@end
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PatternViewCell.h"

@interface collectionViewController :          UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollectionView;

@end
```

---

```
 #import "collectionViewController.h"

@interface collectionViewController ()
@property ( nonatomic, strong) NSArray * patternImagesArray;

@end

@implementation collectionViewController

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 PatternViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PatternCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString * myPatternString = [self.patternImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.patternImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myPatternString];
cell.patternLabel.text = myPatternString;

return cell;
}

-(CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout: (UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return CGSizeMake(150, 150);
}

-(UIEdgeInsets) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.patternImagesArray = @[@"1.png",@"2.png"@"3.png"@"4.png"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView   *)collectionView
 {
  return 1;

 }

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 return self.patternImagesArray.count;

 }


 @end
```

_

Comment: your need to add this method in viewdidload - (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier{  }

Answer (score 0):

Hi make sure to register your cell xib file.

Pop this:

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourXibCellNameHere" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PatternCell"];
```

into your "ViewDidLoad" method in the collectionViewController class. The application needs to know the xib file to populate the UIContentView with.

If you are not using Xib file for your cell just use the name of your custom cell view controller.

Good luck!